# How to set multiple region for AWSServiceManager to use Lex,Rek,S3 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I can't able to set multiple region for AWS Service Manager. 
(Why multiple region? because S3,rekognition->APSoutheast2, Lex -> USWest1.)

When I have used Face Rekognition other Lex always worked on APSoutheast2 region. Check below image. Its seems like able set default only once. How to set for different purpose of using.

PS: Info plist configuration also not taking here.Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the respective service clients as follows:

**S3:**

```
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
            region: .APSoutheast2,
            credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .APSoutheast2, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
        )

        let transferUtilityConfiguration = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()
        transferUtilityConfiguration.isAccelerateModeEnabled = true

        AWSS3TransferUtility.register(
            with: serviceConfiguration!,
            transferUtilityConfiguration: transferUtilityConfiguration,
            forKey: "transfer")
```

**Rekognition:**

```
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
                region: .APSoutheast2,
                credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .APSoutheast2, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
            )

AWSRekognition.register(with: serviceConfiguration!, forKey: "my-rekognition-client")
```

**Lex:**

```
let serviceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
                    region: .USWest1,
                    credentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USWest1, identityPoolId: "YourIdentityPoolId")
                )

    AWSLex.register(with: serviceConfiguration!, forKey: "my-lex-client")
```

Comment: yeap! (y). We are facing the issue in lex listening part. I mean lex could not able to predict to pick intent well in voice to voice chat. our deployed Siri worked well and understand what we spoke but lex return something weird. I have changed the encoding to opus to lpcm. tried on region changes also. Still could not resolve our problem. could you please suggest some solution